# Remedy stuck finalizes without calling GC manually

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

We have a certain set of actions in our C# application which causes the RAM to continue to grow until the form closes. This form is long lived and some users will not close this form for the entire day.

Basically, Form `frmRelationalSearch` calls Form `frmCombinedSearch` to search a person on, and Form `frmCombinedSearch` will return the person back to Form `frmRelationalSearch` when Form `frmCombinedSearch` closes. Form `frmRelationalSearch` is the long lived form here, while Form `frmCombinedSearch` seems to be the one causing problems.

For testing purposes, I've manually added in `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` on each person search cycle to see if it is truly a memory leak. I've realized that the form `frmCombinedSearch` does indeed get collected by the GC and probably is only living long because of it being in the finalizer queue. What I don't get is how to remedy the problem of the growing RAM usage without manually calling `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` in our code wince this is a bad practice.

I've confirmed this using dotMemory and ANTS memory profilers.

How should I handle this? Is it acceptable to call the GC manually in this case?

This is the code right now:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Without these three lines, the RAM will continue to grow until
    // this form (frmRelationalSearch) is closed.

    // GC.Collect();
    // GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    // GC.Collect();

    frmCombinedSearch frm = new frmCombinedSearch();
    try
    {
        // Custom code which just shows the form in the current tab
        frm.ShowInTab(this.ParentTabPage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ShowException(ex);
    }
}
```

In both analyzers, `frmCombinedSearch` gets retained because of the finalizer queue.

**EDIT**:
`ShowInTab()` is non-blocking so I can't use a `using` statement to dispose of it because it would just be disposed right after it's created.

Comment: Are you disposing `frmCombinedSearch` ?

Comment: Can't you move the `frmCombinedSearch` Form logic into a UserControl? Since you apparently want to show that Form inside a TabControl (is it?). So you just need to create the UC once and you can manage and dispose of its resources directly. Btw, you're not showing how/when you're disposing of the `frm` object(s).

Comment: `frmCombineSearch` has `Dispose` called on the forms close event from the designer file. I can't use a `using` statement because if I do, then I will dispose of the form entirely when it's still visible in the TabControl. I would just be opening it and closing it right after.

Comment: Yes, you can and no you cannot call `dispose()` inside the Form class. The class disposes of the resources it initializes, not of itself. You need to dispose of the `frm` object you create in the caller class (`frmRelationalSearch`).

Comment: `frmRelationalSearch` is Disposed when it's closed because it's shown with `form.Show()` inside the `ShowInTab()` method. After a search is done, then it will close.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms need to be closed or disposed ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846663/winforms-when-to-call-dispose-when-is-it-implicit)). I recommend using `using`.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (frmCombinedSearch frm = new frmCombinedSearch())
    {
        try
        {
            // Custom code which just shows the form in the current tab
            frm.ShowInTab(this.ParentTabPage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are `frmCombinedSearch` and `frmRelationalSearch` disposable? If it is you can implement a using so it is collected once closed.

something like below:

```
using(frmCombinedSearch frm = new frmCombinedSearch()){
    try {
       frm.ShowInTab(this.ParentTabPage); }
    catch(Exception ex) {
       this.ShowException(ex); } }
```